# Not enough space between label and title when using \lstlistoflistings

Tags: listings

I'm using the \lstlistoflistings command to generate a list of my listings. Unfortunately there is not enough space between the label and the title (caption).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage
\chapter(Chapter One)
\lstinputlisting[caption=Example for a Dockerfile for building a webserver image]{./Quellcode/Dockerfile}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the generated list of listings]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass  do you use?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}